PDE | Laplace equation exercise
I came across this question as part of my PDE studying:
Let $u(x)$ be a function satisfting:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\Delta u(\vec{x}) = 0 & \vec{x} \in \Omega \\
u(\vec{x}) = 0 & \vec{x} \in \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where: $ n \geq 2$, $\Omega = \{ \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid |\vec{x}| > 1 \}$
Additionally, assume that:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{|\mathbf{x}| \to \infty} u(\mathbf{x}) = 0.
\end{equation*}
and that $u$ is continuous on $\overline{\Omega}$.
Prove that: $u \equiv 0$ On $\Omega$.
At first i thought this was easy using the strong maximum principle, but it did not require me to use the assumption about the limit.
I think I should not assume that $u \in\ C^2$ (in our course in the definition of Harmonic function there is a requirment for it to be in $C^2$).
Can someone please help me solve this?

If the limit condition is removed, then the function $$u = c\left(1-\frac{1}{|\vec{x}|^{n-2}}\right)$$ satisfies the PDE & boundary condition for $n>2$ and any constant $c$. So the assumption is in fact necessary.

Suppose that, for the sake of contradiction, there exists $x_0\in \mathbb R^n \setminus \overline{B_1}$ such that $u(x_0)\neq 0$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $u(x_0)>0$ (otherwise consider $-u$).
Now, by the weak maximum principle for all $R>\vert x_0\vert$, we know that $$\max_{\partial (B_R\setminus B_1)}u=\max_{\overline{B_R\setminus B_1}}u\geq u(x_0)>0\qquad \text{for all } R>\vert x_0\vert.$$ Moreover, since $u=0$ on $\partial B_1$ and $\max_{\overline{B_R\setminus B_1}}u>0$, this implies that the maximum of $u$ in $\overline{B_R\setminus B_1}$ is attained on $\partial B_R$ and $$\max_{\partial B_R}u\geq u(x_0)>0\qquad \text{for all } R>\vert x_0\vert. $$ But this contradicts the assumption $$ \lim_{\vert x \vert \to +\infty} u =0. $$
